# Warning message on GunDB bootup

Tags: gun

There's a warning message when GunDB starts

> WARNING! This `file.js` module for gun is intended only for local development testing!

It doesn't appear to have any negative effect... But it's kinda freaking out the DevOps guys I'm working with. Is there a way to exclude this module... Or at least suppress this message.

Thanks ☺

Answer (score 1):

@jamie-popkin yes, but only if you know that the `file.js` data.json module is not intended for production use cases! If you are using the S3 driver or one of the Level storage adapters then you can try the following:

```
var Gun = require('gun/gun'); // require gun core
require('gun/lib/s3'); // require the S3 driver if you use it.
require('gun/lib/wsp'); // require WebSocket server
```

Note: this setup does not include the `file.js` data.json module at all (which thus prevents the warning message from being logged), which means unless you use the Level storage adapter or provide S3 credentials the database will be running in-memory only.

Very curious to hear what you are working on, shoot me an email? mark AT gunDB dot io . I would feel terrible if I just gave you advice on how to run your app without proper warnings ;) .

p.s. Sorry for the late reply, just got back from a trip in Europe.